# Problema en dimensionar pantalla Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

espero me puedan ayudar, soy algo nuevo en esto, y comencé haciendo una calculadora pero a la hora de instalar la apk en un celular la pantalla no se ve completa, adjunto el xml, creo que el problema esta en el GridLayout pero no logro identificar el error, de antemano muchísimas gracias

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Etiqueta"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:height="120dp"
    android:textColor="#F5F5F5"
    android:textSize="35dp" />

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:rowCount="7"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Clean"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="C"
        android:textColor="#222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Divide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="/"
        android:textColor="#222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Multiplica"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="X"
        android:textColor="#222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Borrar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="Del"
        android:textColor="#222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Siete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="7"
        android:textColor="#222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Ocho"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="8"
        android:textColor="#222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Nueve"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="9"
        android:textColor="#222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Resta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="-"
        android:textColor="#222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Cuatro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="4"
        android:textColor="#222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Cinco"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="5"
        android:textColor="#222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Seis"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="6"
        android:textColor="#222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Suma"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="#222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Uno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Dos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="#222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Tres"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="3"
        android:textColor="#222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Signo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="(+/-)"
        android:textColor="#222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Cero"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Punto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="."
        android:textColor="#222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Factorial"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="x!"
        android:textColor="#222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Igual"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="="
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textColor="#222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Raiz"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="v"
        android:textColor="#222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Porcentaje"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="%"
        android:textColor="#222" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Potencia"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#82228888"
        android:text="x^"
        android:textColor="#222" />
</GridLayout>
```

acá se ve el problema en la pantalla, la parte derecha no sale completa, espero me puedan ayudar, ya he intentado varias cosas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrías que crear otra carpeta "values" dentro del res. Debe darle click derecho y seleccionar la opción "android resource directory", luego se te aparecerá una ventana diciendo el nombre del directorio y el tipo de resource, primero debes cambiar el tipo de resources a values, después en "available qualifiers" debes seleccionar "screen width", esa opción seria un parámetro, de ahí tienes que darle click a una fechita como esta ">>", se te aparecerá un campo de texto en donde vas a tener que ponerle el valor al parámetro que seleccionaste "screen width", ese valor puede ser el que tu quieras, ejemplo: 480, 640, 720, etc (Cuando pongas el valor, sólito se pondrá el nombre del directorio).

Esos serian los valores para cada pantalla de celular. De repente te confundas un poco, pero te explico, tienes que crear nuevamente tu aplicación móvil para que se adapte a cada celular (obviamente solo en el frontend), parecerá ,molesto pero así es android studio, esas carpetas cuando lo subas a la play store, el usuario al momento de descargar tu app, la misma playstore detecta de que tamaño es su celular y dependiendo de ese valor le envía la carpeta "value", si es un celular que tiene una dimensión de 640x1136 la playstore le envia la carpeta "value-640", si es un celular de 750x1334 le envía la carpeta de "value-750", obviamente debes crear esas carpetas, asi que se entiende que debes crear muchas veces tu app o dependiendo de lo que necesites, de repente quieres que se ejecute en 3 modelos de celular, entonces estarías creando 3 carpetas value.

Lo que me estaba olvidando, dentro de esa carpeta debes crear tu archivo xml, debes darle click derecho a esa carpeta y darle en "values resource file", debes darle el nombre "dimens". Ahí tienes que crear etiquetas dimen con su respectivo name, dentro de esas etiquetas debes ponerme un valor, ejemplo: 24dp, 20sp, etc.

Finalmente en tus diseños enves de ponerle un valor a un titulo o aun boton, debes poner el nombre de la etiqueta name que pusiste en tu xml dimens. Eso sería prácticamente todo.

Ahora, con respecto a tu "GridLayout" te explico, de repente estas viendo en la vista previa del celular que te proporciona android studio que esta todo parejo y en su lugar, pero de seguro tu celular debe tener otras dimensiones diferentes al celular que ves en android studio, al momento de instalarlo se distorsionará, ya me ha pasado varias veces.

Espero que te haya servido mucho, acá te dejo un tutorial por si no entendiste, y me disculpo por tanta palabrería pero eso es lo que tienes que saber con respecto a las dimensiones.

Posdata: Me olvide decirte que tu GridLayout esta bien :) en eso no hay problema.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNjX6KtHUKo

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta me aclaro bastantes cosas que las tenia enredadas, y no estaba muy complicado lo escrito :) aun así el vídeo ayudo muchísimo

Comment: No olvides marcar el check para poner que es la tarjeta. :)